# Angularjs and google map, setting a scope variable a value from the map on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I think this is a problem in angularjs and not specifically in wrong usage of a google map directive.

I have a map markup using a directive like so.

```
<map>
   <marker on-click="setSelected(e,item)"></marker>
</map>
```

and in my controller

```
$scope.selectedItem = {};
$scope.setSelected = function(e,item){
 $scope.selectedItem = item;
 // console.log($scope.selectedItem)
}
```

When I log the `selectedItem`, I am getting the expected result, but when I try to use the variable in a template, it just don't work at all like so

```
<p>{{selectedItem}}</p>
```

What do you think is the mistake here.

Comment: For more clarification you could post a working JSFiddle.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap everything within the function `setSelected` around an AngularJS `$apply` like so:

```
$scope.setSelected = function(e,item){
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.selectedItem = item;
    });
}
```